# Gradle project refresh fails after adding Google Play Services

Tags: android, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin

So after i add Google Play Services in dependencies, Gradle fails to sync and i get: **Cannot change configuration ':android:compile' after it has been resolved play services** error.

Only similar thing i have found in this 2 questions: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569581/gradle-cant-manage-to-add-compile-com-google-android-gmsplay-services7-0-0) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155475/could-not-find-com-google-android-gmsplay-services3-1-59-3-2-25-4-0-30-4-1-32), but it is not helping me. Also i have everything up to date, also i have added ANDROID_HOME variable just to make sure. But it's still the same

I use Android studio and libGDX if there is any connection with those two and the problem.

Build.gradle(module: android)

```
android {
buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
compileSdkVersion 23
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
}
}
// needed to add JNI shared libraries to APK when compiling on CLI
tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
pkgTask.jniFolders = new HashSet<File>()
pkgTask.jniFolders.add(new File(projectDir, 'libs'))
}
// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() {
file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
    def outputDir = null
    if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
    if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
    if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
    if (outputDir != null) {
        copy {
            from zipTree(jar)
            into outputDir
            include "*.so"
        }
    }
}
}
 task run(type: Exec) {
def path
def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
if (localProperties.exists()) {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
        properties.load(instr)
    }
    def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
    if (sdkDir) {
        path = sdkDir
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }
} else {
    path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
}

def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'path.to.project.android/path.to.project.android.AndroidLauncher'
}
// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
// need to specify Java source sets explicitely, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
// ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
    }
}

jdt {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.6
    targetCompatibility = 1.6
}

classpath {
    plusConfigurations += project.configurations.compile
    containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'
}

project {
    name = appName + "-android"
    natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
    buildCommands.clear();
    buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
    buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
    buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
    buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
}
    }
// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
module {
    sourceDirs += file("src");
    scopes = [COMPILE: [plus: [project.configurations.compile]]]

    iml {
        withXml {
            def node = it.asNode()
            def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
            builder.current = node;
            builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                    configuration {
                        option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value: "true")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
}
```

EDIT: with futher testing and trying, i have figured out that i can't add anything in dependencies. Error is the same

Comment: Show us your gradle file

Comment: i have eddited the question

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is that you are adding the `dependencies` block **outside** the `android` block. Look carefully at your braces. If that still doesn't fix it, there is already an android dependencies section in the top level build.gradle file in a libgdx project. Try putting them there instead.

Comment: it is that in default. I have put everything in android bracelets but it is the same.

Then i have dependencies in android gradle build. If i put in in core gradle dependencies it says it doesnt find services